# Is there a possibility to display the changesets in a mercurial bundle?

Tags: mercurial

The [mercurial wiki](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/LookingIntoBundles?highlight=%28bundle%29) has hints on how to display the changesets a bundle would add to a given repository.

Is there a possibility to display the changesets (and log messages) contained in a bundle independent of a specific repository?

**EDIT:** The reason for my question is that
sometimes I have one repository at work and one at home. I use
bundles on a USB stick to keep them synchronised.

Once in a while I want to check whether the bundle contains all
the changesets that it's supposed to contain. I can't check it
with the source repository because it already contains all the
changesets in the bundle. (I can check it with the target repository, but
that's not much help since then I can't access the source
repository.)

Of course, when in doubt you can always recreate the bundle, so
this isn't much of a problem. I just wondered whether it is
possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re-edit**

Using an outgoing repository (which contains the already transferred changesets), bundling against that, and then applying the bundle to that repo after you put it on your stick would count as such a check. At least, that's how I'm doing what you describe.

Comment: Sadly, not for me. In both cases, hg complains about an unknown parent. I am using mercurial 1.2.1. What version do you use?

Comment: Ok, it is not a version problem.